# STRING_AGG Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was working with SQL Server 2017 and I used the following query,

```
select 
  'select s.' + string_agg (c.source_column + ', t.' + c.target_column, ', ') +
  ' from ' + t.source_table + ' s' +
  ' join ' + t.target_table + ' t' +
  ' on ' + string_agg('t.' + c.target_column + ' = s.' + c.source_column, ' and ') +
  ';' as query
from configuration_tables t
join configuration_columns c on c.id_configuration_tables = t.id_configuration_tables
group by t.source_table, t.target_table
order by t.source_table, t.target_table;
```

The query is used to get the list of columns in a string for each table name.

I have to move to 2016 due to some issues, I modified the query as below,

```
select 
        distinct 'select ' + STUFF((select ','  + 's.[' + c1.source_column  + '],t.[' + c1.target_column + ']' 
        from recon_configuration_columns c1 where c1.id_recon_configuration_table = c.id_recon_configuration_table FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 
        + ' from ' + t.source_table + ' s' +
        ' join ' + t.target_table + ' t' +
        ' on ' + STUFF((select ' and ' + 's.[' + c1.source_column  + '] = t.[' + c1.target_column + '] ' from recon_configuration_columns c1 
        where c1.id_recon_configuration_table = c.id_recon_configuration_table FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,5,'')
from    
    recon_configuration_tables t
    join recon_configuration_columns c on c.id_recon_configuration_table = t.id_recon_configuration_table
```

I would like to know whether the query I changed is a standard one, also it wont create any problems in long run and always both queries should return the same results.

Thanks for your support

Comment: providing sample data would help

Comment: Hi, I have tested with various data and found that both queries return same results. I am closing the question as no longer support needed for this query.

Comment: Please add this as answer and mark it as answer, so it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: @RealisticDeals, as the person who posted the question, you can't "close" it, the way that word is used on Stack Overflow, but you can delete it. There's a button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: The second query has no ORDER BY clause (before FOR XML), so it may provide different results.